# Loop through a list compare to another list and delete if the same

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to lookup a range of values in sheet 4 column A (there's about 100), then use this list to look through a much bigger list (200,000 rows) in sheet 2 column C. For every value that appears in sheet 4 column A i want to check each row in sheet 2 Column c and if a value matches then I want to delete the whole row in sheet 2.

I have this code below:

But it doesn't seem to work, says there is an object error

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
Dim rng As Range
Dim I As Long, J As Integer
Dim myCell As Range
Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet4").["A1:A" & Range("A" & 
Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)"]
With rng
For I = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
For J = 1 To .Columns.Count
For Each myCell In Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C1:C" & Range("C" & 
Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
If .Cells(I, J).Value = myCell Then
.Cells(I, J).EntireRow.Delete xlUp
Exit For
End If
Next
Next J
Next I
End With
Set rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Any help would be great!

Many thanks

Comment: Debug your code and provide clear information: what does error says and where (what line) it happens.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that in,

Comment: Runtime error 424, object required,  line 5

Comment: Your line 5 doesn't make any sense. No square brackets for indexing in VBA, also `object.[...]` is not a valid construct. Try this instead: `Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)`

Comment: change your line 5 to `Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having 2 `For` loops, you can have 1 `For` that will loop through all cells in Column "C" in `Worksheets("Sheet2")`, and for each row, use the `Application.Match` to see if there's a match in column "A" in `Worksheets("Sheet4")`.

**Note**: allways loop backwards when deleting rows.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

' set up Matched Range
Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    ' get last row in column C
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    ' allways loop backwards when deleting rows
    For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        ' check if successful match 
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Range("C" & i).Value, Rng, 0)) Then
            .Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i    
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: is there anyway of speeding it up you know of, that I could try?

Comment: @Ollie I've added a small twick, see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use ADODB within the macro which can give you the result in seconds

Sub Filter()

Dim con As New ADODB.Connection

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String

DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName  'Refering the sameworkbook as Data Source

'You can provide the full path of your external file as shown below
'DBPath ="C:\InputData.xlsx"

sconnect = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes';"

'If any issue with MSDASQL Provider, Try the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB:
'sconnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & DBPath _
& ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

con.Open sconnect

sSQLSting = "SELECT * From [Sheet2$] WHERE ColC not in (SELECT ColA FROM [Sheet1$])" ' Your SQL Statement (Table Name= Sheet Name=[Sheet1$])

rs.Open sSQLSting, con

Sheet3.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

End Sub



NOTE : In the Excel Code editor go to TOOLS->References and set a reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library
```